# Quadro K2100M OBS Studio not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, obs-studio

Before I updated (clean install) from 18.04 to 20.04, OBS worked fine on my Nvidia Quadro K2100M. After updating, I am met with the below messages. This happens in the launchpad and unofficial snap versions. I have the `nvidia-driver-418-server` package installed from "Additional Drivers". Any help would be appreciated.

[image: OBS failed to open NVENC codec error.]

When run from the terminal, I get this message:

```
info: ---------------------------------
info: [NVENC encoder: 'streaming_h264'] settings:
    rate_control: CBR
    bitrate:      2500
    cqp:          0
    keyint:       60
    preset:       hq
    profile:      high
    width:        1280
    height:       720
    2-pass:       false
    b-frames:     2
    GPU:          0

[h264_nvenc @ 0x563aff391b00] Driver does not support the required nvenc API version. Required: 9.1 Found: 9.0
[h264_nvenc @ 0x563aff391b00] The minimum required Nvidia driver for nvenc is 435.21 or newer
warning: [NVENC encoder: 'streaming_h264'] Failed to open NVENC codec: Function not implemented
```

Output of `uname -a`, `inxi -G`, `lspci`, `obs --version` and `dpkg -l | egrep '(\ obs|libobs|nvidia)'`:

```
gekepdp@laptop:~$ uname -a
Linux laptop 5.8.0-55-generic #62~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 2 08:55:04 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
gekepdp@laptop:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] driver: nvidia v: 460.80 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Quadro K2100M/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.80
```

```
gekepdp@laptop:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
11:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
```

```
gekepdp@laptop:~$ obs --version
OBS Studio - 27.0.0 (linux)
```

```
gekepdp@laptop:~$ dpkg -l | egrep '(\ obs|libobs|nvidia)'
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-460:amd64                   460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-460                       460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-418-server:amd64         418.197.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-460:amd64                460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-460:i386                 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-460:amd64                 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-460:i386                  460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-460:amd64                 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-460:i386                  460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-460:amd64                  460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-460:amd64                   460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386                    460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-460:amd64                     460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-460:i386                      460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-460:amd64                   460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386                    460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-418-server            418.197.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-460                   460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-418-server                     418.197.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-dkms-460                            460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-435                          455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1            amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-driver-455
ii  nvidia-driver-455                          460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-driver-460
ii  nvidia-driver-460                          460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-418-server            418.197.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-460                   460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-460                   460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.16~0.20.04.1                      all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-460                           460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  obs-studio                                 27.0.0-0obsproject1~focal             amd64        OBS Studio for Ubuntu
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18build1                            all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460              460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

The complete output of the OBS command is below - I tried recording and then exited the program after it failed:

```
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-GB.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-GB.ini
info: Using preferred locale 'en-GB'
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
info: CPU Name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600M CPU @ 2.90GHz
info: CPU Speed: 2984.634MHz
info: Physical Cores: 2, Logical Cores: 4
info: Physical Memory: 15918MB Total, 11543MB Free
info: Kernel Version: Linux 5.8.0-55-generic
info: Distribution: "Ubuntu" "20.04"
info: Session Type: x11
info: Window System: X11.0, Vendor: The X.Org Foundation, Version: 1.20.9
info: Portable mode: false
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_tbar_position_valueChanged(int)
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionShowTransitionProperties_triggered()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionHideTransitionProperties_triggered()
info: OBS 27.0.0 (linux)
info: ---------------------------------
info: ---------------------------------
info: audio settings reset:
    samples per sec: 48000
    speakers:        2
info: ---------------------------------
info: Initializing OpenGL...
info: Loading up OpenGL on adapter NVIDIA Corporation Quadro K2100M/PCIe/SSE2
info: OpenGL loaded successfully, version 3.3.0 NVIDIA 460.80, shading language 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
info: ---------------------------------
info: video settings reset:
    base resolution:   1920x1080
    output resolution: 1280x720
    downscale filter:  Bicubic
    fps:               30/1
    format:            NV12
    YUV mode:          709/Partial
info: NV12 texture support not available
info: Audio monitoring device:
    name: Default
    id: default
info: ---------------------------------
warning: Failed to load 'en-US' text for module: 'decklink-captions.so'
warning: Failed to load 'en-US' text for module: 'decklink-ouput-ui.so'
libDeckLinkAPI.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
warning: A DeckLink iterator could not be created.  The DeckLink drivers may not be installed
info: No blackmagic support
info: [obs-browser]: Version 2.14.3
info: [obs-browser]: CEF Version 87.1.12+g03f9336+chromium-87.0.4280.88
info: NVENC supported
info: FFMPEG VAAPI supported
info: VLC found, VLC video source enabled
info: ---------------------------------
info:   Loaded Modules:
info:     vlc-video.so
info:     text-freetype2.so
info:     rtmp-services.so
info:     obs-x264.so
info:     obs-vst.so
info:     obs-transitions.so
info:     obs-outputs.so
info:     obs-libfdk.so
info:     obs-filters.so
info:     obs-ffmpeg.so
info:     obs-browser.so
info:     linux-v4l2.so
info:     linux-pulseaudio.so
info:     linux-jack.so
info:     linux-decklink.so
info:     linux-capture.so
info:     linux-alsa.so
info:     image-source.so
info:     frontend-tools.so
info:     decklink-ouput-ui.so
info:     decklink-captions.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: ==== Startup complete ===============================================
info: All scene data cleared
info: ------------------------------------------------
info: pulse-input: Server name: 'pulseaudio 13.99.1'
info: pulse-input: Audio format: s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
info: pulse-input: Started recording from 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor'
info: [Loaded global audio device]: 'Desktop Audio'
info: pulse-input: Server name: 'pulseaudio 13.99.1'
info: pulse-input: Audio format: s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
info: pulse-input: Started recording from 'alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo'
info: [Loaded global audio device]: 'Mic/Aux'
info: Switched to scene 'Scene'
info: ------------------------------------------------
info: Loaded scenes:
info: - scene 'Scene':
info: ------------------------------------------------
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/images/overflow.png
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/images/overflow.png
info: adding 42 milliseconds of audio buffering, total audio buffering is now 42 milliseconds (source: Mic/Aux)

info: ---------------------------------
info: [NVENC encoder: 'streaming_h264'] settings:
    rate_control: CBR
    bitrate:      2500
    cqp:          0
    keyint:       60
    preset:       hq
    profile:      high
    width:        1280
    height:       720
    2-pass:       false
    b-frames:     2
    psycho-aq:    1
    GPU:          0

[h264_nvenc @ 0x55c81e3a2800] No NVENC capable devices found
warning: [NVENC encoder: 'streaming_h264'] Failed to open NVENC codec: Generic error in an external library
info: ==== Shutting down ==================================================
info: pulse-input: Stopped recording from 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor'
info: pulse-input: Got 2034 packets with 450092 frames
info: pulse-input: Stopped recording from 'alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo'
info: pulse-input: Got 1216 packets with 537216 frames
info: All scene data cleared
info: ------------------------------------------------
error: X Error: GLXBadDrawable, Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: 26, Serial: 5359
error: Failed to make context current.
error: X Error: GLXBadDrawable, Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: 26, Serial: 5361
error: Failed to make context current.
error: X Error: GLXBadDrawable, Major opcode: 152, Minor opcode: 26, Serial: 5363
error: Failed to make context current.
info: [Scripting] Total detached callbacks: 0
info: Freeing OBS context data
info: == Profiler Results =============================
info: run_program_init: 882.557 ms
info:  ┣OBSApp::AppInit: 6.888 ms
info:  ┃ ┗OBSApp::InitLocale: 3.603 ms
info:  ┗OBSApp::OBSInit: 684.271 ms
info:    ┣obs_startup: 1.393 ms
info:    ┗OBSBasic::OBSInit: 615.277 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitBasicConfig: 0.49 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetAudio: 0.182 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetVideo: 80.406 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitOBSCallbacks: 0.002 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitHotkeys: 0.059 ms
info:      ┣obs_load_all_modules: 346.455 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(decklink-captions.so): 0.041 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(decklink-ouput-ui.so): 0.634 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(frontend-tools.so): 92.523 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(image-source.so): 0.009 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-alsa.so): 0.004 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-capture.so): 0.405 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-decklink.so): 0.18 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-jack.so): 0.003 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-pulseaudio.so): 0.002 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-v4l2.so): 2.865 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-browser.so): 0.077 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-ffmpeg.so): 12.192 ms
info:      ┃ ┃ ┗nvenc_check: 12.08 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-filters.so): 0.029 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-libfdk.so): 0.003 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-outputs.so): 0.005 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-transitions.so): 0.011 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-vst.so): 0.004 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-x264.so): 0.002 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(rtmp-services.so): 2.054 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(text-freetype2.so): 0.018 ms
info:      ┃ ┗obs_init_module(vlc-video.so): 2.761 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetOutputs: 0.565 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::CreateHotkeys: 0.197 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitService: 2.12 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitPrimitives: 0.226 ms
info:      ┗OBSBasic::Load: 87.471 ms
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=0.119 ms, median=0.471 ms, max=5.055 ms, 99th percentile=1.343 ms, 100% below 25 ms
info: audio_thread(Audio): min=0 ms, median=0.091 ms, max=1.339 ms, 99th percentile=0.5 ms
info: obs_graphics_thread(33.3333 ms): min=0.372 ms, median=1.53 ms, max=43.953 ms, 99th percentile=6.607 ms, 99.7375% below 33.333 ms
info:  ┣tick_sources: min=0.001 ms, median=0.009 ms, max=0.193 ms, 99th percentile=0.024 ms
info:  ┣output_frame: min=0.129 ms, median=0.389 ms, max=5.725 ms, 99th percentile=2.224 ms
info:  ┃ ┗gs_context(video->graphics): min=0.129 ms, median=0.388 ms, max=5.724 ms, 99th percentile=2.222 ms
info:  ┃   ┣render_video: min=0.058 ms, median=0.111 ms, max=0.866 ms, 99th percentile=0.506 ms
info:  ┃   ┃ ┗render_main_texture: min=0.048 ms, median=0.09 ms, max=0.846 ms, 99th percentile=0.321 ms
info:  ┃   ┗gs_flush: min=0.006 ms, median=0.015 ms, max=0.199 ms, 99th percentile=0.059 ms
info:  ┗render_displays: min=0.061 ms, median=0.703 ms, max=41.419 ms, 99th percentile=2.389 ms
info: =================================================
info: == Profiler Time Between Calls ==================
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=25.2 ms, median=25.58 ms, max=30.172 ms, 34.2% within ±2% of 25 ms (0% lower, 65.8% higher)
info: obs_graphics_thread(33.3333 ms): min=22.719 ms, median=33.333 ms, max=43.957 ms, 99.4737% within ±2% of 33.333 ms (0.263158% lower, 0.263158% higher)
info: =================================================
info: Number of memory leaks: 0
```

Comment: I don't see `libnvidia-encode-460-server` also why not install same version (460) of `nvidia-compute-utils-418-server`, `nvidia-dkms-418-server` , Could you add the output of `ffmpeg -version`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your hardware does not support required nvenc version, change encoder in settings.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2**:
Please post the complete output of the following commands:

```
$ obs
```

---

Please post the complete output of the following commands:

```
$ uname -a
$ inxi -G
$ lspci
$ obs --version
$ dpkg -l | egrep '(\ obs|libobs|nvidia)'
```

---

You seem to have an old nvidia driver.
What might work:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-465
sudo reboot
```

Note: I posted `465` since it is the latest I see with tab completion after typing `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-`. You may have a different version, but it will surely be enough (probably >435) ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269433/the-minimum-required-nvidia-driver-for-nvenc-is-435-21-or-newer)).

I don't think you need to [compile from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778100/how-to-install-compile-nvenc-in-ubuntu).

Comment: @gekepdp - I do not understand your question. Did you try updating the driver as suggested in the answer?
I guess you didn't, otherwise I expected to see it in your image.

Comment: Sorry, I read your answer completely wrong - I have now completed these steps but I am now getting this error message - `[h264_nvenc @ 0x55750a6d44c0] No NVENC capable devices found
warning: [NVENC encoder: 'streaming_h264'] Failed to open NVENC codec: Generic error in an external library
`

Comment: @gekepdp - https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/creative-apps/26/297449/failed-to-open-nvenc-codec-generic-error-in-an-ext/

Comment: @gekepdp - https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/failed-to-open-nvenc-codec-generic-error-in-an-external-library-i-have-tried-everything.112568/

Comment: @gekepdp - Try using other application than OBS, e.g., `ffmpeg` ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146566/ffmpeg-h264-nvenc-no-nvenc-capable-devices-found), [2](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5926), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948737/ffmpeg-hevc-nvenc-no-nvenc-capable-devices-found-with-nvidia-gtx950m)), plus [using flag `-loglevel`](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/h265-to-h264-transcode-no-nvenc-capable-devices-found/57548), to isolate the problem.

Comment: It seems to have worked fine - the video is perfect and the log has no errors - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/j8pzsMCtQ5/ and https://streamable.com/v4wp5l . OBS still isn't working though?

Comment: @gekepdp - Please see EDIT 2.
Does OBS start, even with the output posted?