# Upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and laptop's Primary Display is Not Working

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display, intel-graphics

I was on 20.04, and both displays were working without any issues. But, ever since I upgraded to 22.04, only the external display is working, and the primary display is black with a non-blinking cursor. (It blinks initially but stays stable after the external display starts output).

I tried removing xorg.conf file and placing a blank xorg.conf file. This results in both of the displays not working.

If I change the `prime-select` to intel and primary display works and the external display doesn't show any output.

I tried adding the intel device to xorg.conf but, it's not working, as well.

Here's `lspci | grep "VGA"`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
```

`xrandr -q`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   3840x2160     29.97 +  29.97    25.00    23.98
   2560x1440     59.95
   1920x1080     60.00*   59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98
   1680x1050     59.95
   1600x1200     60.00
   1600x900      60.00
   1440x480      59.94
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x800      59.81
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       59.94
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Does this work for you?: https://askubuntu.com/a/1446717/321777

Comment: @AaronD Unfortunately, my laptop BIOS doesn't have this feature. :(

Comment: It might be named differently.  Here's the one that I referenced to fix mine: https://askubuntu.com/a/1446682/321777  Yours might be different again.  Or it could be that you really don't have it, in which case, I really don't know.

Comment: @AaronD No, it's not there, which is unfortunate.  I was expecting discrete GPU settings in BIOS.